# Autosize for cover long multiple textbox WP8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, textbox

I just created textbox in xaml. It is probably filled by very long text.

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtStory" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="456" MinHeight="200" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
```

My problem is when i type in multiple line, it will cropped like this[image: cropped]

What should i do to make textbox with scrolling or another method that i can use? Thank you

Comment: please try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908225/how-to-give-scrolling-in-textbox/35667083#35667083

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the maximum height of the ScrollViewer and could set the Visibility for the Scrollbars to Auto.

[Follow this link for more info](http://vigneshradhakrishnan.blogspot.in/2012/11/scrollable-textbox-silverlightwp7.html)

```
 <ScrollViewer Height="200" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtStory" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="TextBox" Width="460">

        </TextBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

in above example you could set ScrollViewer height according to your need

Comment: This would slve your problem