# Windows Phone 8 Scroll content of textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, scrollviewer

Problem: I am not able to see my pointer while typing inside `TextBox` when i enters large text inside `TextBox`

Description:

1. whenever user enters text inside `TextBox`, if entered text is large then scrolling should be enabled.
2. `ScrollViewer` is showing only content of `TextBox` within height of `ScrollViewer`
3. as I enters few lines of text problem arises(pointer is not visible)
4. then I'll scroll downward to see pointer, after entering few more lines problem arises again

Code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="Scroll Content Inside Textbox" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="25,0,180,0"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <ScrollViewer Height="200"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBox x:Name="txtBody"
                     Width="200"
                     AcceptsReturn="True"
                     />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: This is my post for same problem... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208133/autosize-for-cover-long-multiple-textbox-wp8/23209576#23209576

Comment: in your solution same problem arises after 11 lines

Comment: try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908225/how-to-give-scrolling-in-textbox/35667083#35667083

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="Scroll Content Inside Textbox" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="25,0,180,0"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <ScrollViewer Height="200"
                Name="scrlView"
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBox x:Name="txtBody"
                     Width="200"
                     AcceptsReturn="True" KeyUp="txtBody_KeyUp"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    private void txtBody_KeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
        {
            scrlView.UpdateLayout();
            scrlView.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrlView.ExtentHeight);
        }
    }
```

Trick:

(1) Named ScrollViewer as scrlView

(2) I have written code in KeyUp event of TextBox

(3) Whenever user hit Enter key, then scroll down the TextBox through code

Thank you everyone for your valuable time and support

Comment: this brings the focus at the last line every time. Suppose i have entered 10 lines and i now i want to edit 1st line, that time also focus will be on last line, not on first line, is there anyway to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 3):

What you have to do is to basically put content of textbox in scrollviewer.
This is old code but you should be able to see the pointer and scroll on demand. (As far as I remember, I have no possibility to test it right now)
You might also find necessary to put this textbox in following Scrollviewer, but it may work without it. Unfortunately Height of Textbox have to be hard coded (If you put it in scrollvierer height, or maxheight of scrollviewer has to be hardcoded.)
Hope it helps (and works)!

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                MaxHeight="150"
                Name="scroll"
                />





<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="text" InputScope="Chat"
                         Name="message"
                         Height="Auto"
                         Style="{StaticResource ScrollableTextBox}"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"
                         AcceptsReturn="True"  TextChanged="MessageTextChanged" />


<Style x:Key="ScrollableTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectionBackground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectionForeground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxSelectionForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ReadonlyBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxReadOnlyBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="MainBorder">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="MainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"/>
                            <Border x:Name="ReadonlyBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="Transparent" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxInnerMargin}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the text box in a `StackPanel` so that it has something to expand into.  For example:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
      <TextBox x:Name="txtBody"
                     Width="200"
                     AcceptsReturn="True"
                     />
    </StackPanel>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thats another way of doing it, but problem is same